# Binding to Canvas.TopProperty with adding some value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have this code:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="cage" Height="247" Canvas.Left="278" Canvas.Top="220" Width="450">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="resources/cage.gif"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

and

```
<Label x:Name="to1" Content="1" Canvas.Left="550" Canvas.Top="{Binding Source=cage, Path=Canvas.Top, Mode=OneWay}"  BorderBrush="#FF272727" BorderThickness="1" Height="38" Width="38" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" PreviewMouseDown="to1_PreviewMouseDown"/>
```

Binding is working, but I want to maintain locations of this element relative to each other. Another words, if i shift the cage, topProperty of label became "shifting value + 285". How to do this?

Comment: Use a     Converter. See: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a converter for this purpose as bit suggested.

A simple example should look like this:

**XAML**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converterNamespace:LabelOffsetConverter x:Key="labelOffsetConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Label x:Name="to1" Content="1" Canvas.Left="550" 
       Canvas.Top="{Binding Source=cage, Path=Canvas.Top, Mode=OneWay,
                    Converter={StaticResource labelOffsetConverter}"
       BorderBrush="#FF272727" 
       BorderThickness="1" 
       Height="38" Width="38" 
       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
       VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
       FontSize="20" PreviewMouseDown="to1_PreviewMouseDown"/>
```

**Converter Code**

```
public class LabelOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is double))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        double doubleValue = (double)value;
        return doubleValue + 285;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // No need to implement, since the binding is in one way mode.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you **do** read the article that _bit_ posted as a comment to your question.
You should understand the basics of converters before approaching this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by this way:
**C#**

```
public class Label1offset : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is double))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
```

`double doubleValue = (double)value;
        return doubleValue + 65.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // No need to implement, since the binding is in one way mode.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
Binding binding1 = new Binding();
            binding1.Converter = new Label1offset();
            binding1.Source = cage;
            binding1.Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty);
            binding1.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            to1.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, binding1);`